# WLAN very slow at campus (many other laptops connected to same wifi), how to improve speed?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, speed, connection, performance

I have an Acer 1810TZ (Win 7 Pro 64bit) with a **Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN**. When I'm connected to access points, where only 2 or 3 other devices are connected at the same time, the speed of my wlan is ok.

But at campus I'm havding the problem that my wlan speed sucks, but my classmates don't have slow internet. It's not the AP, I think it is the configuration of my wlan card.

Ping to google.com:

```
Package loss of 30%, ping between 135ms-1735ms, average 670ms
```

I tried the following things:

- disable/enable wlan
- install the newest driver from intel support (really the up to date version from march 2011)
- read the following topics:

  - [How to increase wifi speed for laptops](https://superuser.com/questions/121647/how-to-increase-wifi-speed-for-laptops)
  - [About 1/3 of web sites load really slow on my desktop connected to wifi, but not on my iPod Touch connected to the same wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/286004/about-1-3-of-web-sites-load-really-slow-on-my-desktop-connected-to-wifi-but-not)
  - [Wireless very slow on one laptop on network, all other machines normal?](https://superuser.com/questions/129645/wireless-very-slow-on-one-laptop-on-network-all-other-machines-normal)
  - [WiFi dropping every 1-2 minutes only on campus network](https://superuser.com/questions/180250/wifi-dropping-every-1-2-minutes-only-on-campus-network)

My config:

```
802.11n channel bandwich for 2.4: 20MHz
802.11n Mode: activated
Wireless Mode 802.11b/g
Fat Channel Intolleracen: deactivated
Roaming dynamic level: medium
CTS-to-self activated
Transmissionpower: max
```

What possibilities do I have to analyze the problem or even solve it?

Comment: To help troubleshoot, I'd start with [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/).

Answer (score 2):

If your wireless adapter and campus network support the 5GHz band, it's almost always a much cleaner signal, i.e. less interference.

Comment: mhh. my device doesn't support 5GHz :-/

Comment: If the poor performance is due to interference, his friends should experience the same problem which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data transmission rate. If you are close to the access point it should be very high or maximum (54Mbps in 802.11g network). Some rate selection algorithms are very poor and decrease the data transmission rate significantly hoping to get a better throughput. If the rate is low manually set it to a high rate (if you are relevantly close to the AP).
Second thing I would do in such a situation is to turn on CTS/RTS it usually helps in busy networks. Let me know if you don't know how to do these.